# Comparing gestures/images in Android

Tags: android, image, comparison, compare, gesture

What would be the best way to compare a gesture made on an Android device's screen with a stored gesture?  For example, if in my application, I want it so that if I draw a triangle with my finger, the screen will turn blue, and if I draw a circle, the screen will turn red, how could that be done?  The only thing I have been able to think of so far is to somehow generate an image file and then compare that to an image of a triangle or circle and check for similarities.  But that wouldn't really account for different sized shapes or offset ones.  Any ideas on how this could be implemented?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to compare/match the shape of a gesture with an image. The better way is to mathematically *guess* which one of the recognized shapes did the user draw. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html provides a great reference for implementing gestures.

HTH,

Akshay